# How to tell if site uses forms-authentication

Tags: forms-authentication

Can anybody tell me if the following site uses forms-authentication or something else?
http://www.hammernutrition.com/forums/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=1323

Answer (score 3):

Yes it does.  View the source of the page and do a search for `password`.  Forms-based authentication apps generally have login code that looks like this:

```
<form action="/path/to/login_handler" method="post"> 
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <input type="submit" value="login">
</form>
```

Comment: There are 3 form action: <form action="" method="post" id="searchform" onsubmit="doSearch('searchform','http://www.hammernutrition.com/search/'); return false;"> <form action="./search.php?sid=471d78a42c50025d668d237f3eaf8e2a" method="post" id="search"> <form action="./ucp.php?mode=login&amp;sid=471d78a42c50025d668d237f3eaf8e2a" method="post" id="login">. Which one is it?

Comment: Which one looks like a login action?

Comment: In the URL given in my initial question, i could find several instances where the word password appears, but not with a form tag. So I'm still clueless as to where the login with password takes place, and how I could program it in Python to automatically open the page.

Comment: I have to wonder why you would want to programatically log into a message board.  Often it is for nefarious purposes.

Comment: I have to organize the information of many users in a forum to which I belong. I'm trying to automate it with a Python script that handles cookies. However, the code I utilized for forms-authentication didn't work, and somebody suggested that I have to click the login button.